# How to improve performance of a stored procedure called from a web page?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.5, php

This is my first SQL stored procedure

```
$sql  = ("CALL Login_Details($ID);");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

mysqli_next_result($conn);
```

When I run the second procedure the page is taking more time to load

This is the second procedure

```
$project = ("CALL Project($id);");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $project);
```

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ABC`@`%` PROCEDURE `Project`(id INT)
BEGIN

SELECT project.year, project.serial_no, project.description, 
  project.location, assignment.ID AS Assignment_ID, 
  assignment.assgin_name, hub_coordinator.Employee_ID AS Coordinator_ID
FROM (project INNER JOIN assignment ON project.ID = assignment.Project_ID) 
INNER JOIN hub_coordinator ON assignment.ID = hub_coordinator.Assign_ID
GROUP BY 
 project.Year, project.serial_no, project.description, project.location, 
 assignment.ID, assignment.assgin_name, hub_coordinator.Employee_ID
HAVING (((hub_coordinator.Employee_ID)=id) )
ORDER BY assignment.ID DESC;
    
END
```

Comment: You obviously need to tune the query; the fact that it is in a stored procedure is largely irrelevant. For one, you should move the `(hub_coordinator.Employee_ID)=id` predicate to the corresponding join condition to avoid aggregation of the entire table.

Comment: I tried to Tune it but it still doesn't work could you please guide me through how I can properly tune it for a better speed result.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Where does `id` come from in the `HAVING`?  Please qualify it.

The `HAVING` maybe should be `WHERE`?  Or `ON`?

Some of these composite indexes may help:

```
assignment:  INDEX(Project_ID, assgin_name)
hub_coordinator:  INDEX(Employee_ID, Assign_ID)
hub_coordinator:  INDEX(Assign_ID, Employee_ID)
```